# What is qt6-tools equivalent of qt5-tool uic option?

Tags: linux, qt

What is qt6-tools equivalent of qt5-tool uic option?

Looking thru qt6-tool help is not so helpful.

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ qt6-tools --help
Usage: qt6-tools [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  androiddeployqt
  androidtestrunner
  assistant
  designer
  lconvert
  linguist
  lrelease
  lupdate
  pixeltool
  qdbus
  qdbuscpp2xml
  qdbusviewer
  qdbusxml2cpp
  qdistancefieldgenerator
  qdoc
  qmake
  qmake6
  qml
  qmldom
  qmleasing
  qmlformat
  qmllint
  qmlls
  qmlplugindump
  qmlpreview
  qmlprofiler
  qmlscene
  qmltc
  qmltestrunner
  qmltime
  qt-cmake
  qt-cmake-private
  qt-cmake-standalone-test
  qt-configure-module
  qtdiag
  qtdiag6
  qtpaths
  qtpaths6
  qtplugininfo
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems now to be a built-in tool : [link1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file-python.html) and [link2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/uic.html). Is that your question?